# pandas - groupby identifier & date and compute cumulative returns across different horizons

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Given a DataFrame that looks like this:

```
           ticker         date       return
0            AAPL   2012-12-31     0.032615
1            AAPL   2013-01-02     0.036938
2            AAPL   2013-01-03     0.023232
3            AAPL   2013-01-04     0.014632
5            AMZN   2013-01-07    -0.007089
6            AMZN   2013-01-08     0.003060
7            AMZN   2013-01-09    -0.015760
8            AMZN   2013-01-10    -0.019112
9            GOOG   2012-12-31     0.032615
10           GOOG   2013-01-02     0.036938
11           GOOG   2013-01-03     0.023232
12           GOOG   2013-01-04     0.014632
13           GOOG   2013-01-07    -0.017902
13           GOOG   2013-01-08    -0.007089
14           GOOG   2013-01-09     0.003060
15           GOOG   2013-01-10    -0.015760
```

My objective is that for every row, I am able to have another column that tells me what that ticker's cumulative return will be for 5, 21, 63, and 252 day ahead periods. For instance, a 5 day ahead cumulative return for GOOG on 12/31/2012 I can compute by doing:

```
((1 + df.iloc[9:13]['return']).cumprod()-1).iloc[-1].shift(-5)
```

However, I want to do this as efficiently as possible. I know how to groupby ticker & date, but how can I also cumulate returns over some horizon and shift them back at the same time? Is this even possible in pandas?

Comment: Are your sure that return is `prod` not `sum`?

Comment: @QuangHoang yes, when you cumulate returns you take a product.

Comment: `df.groupby('ticker').return.rolling(5).apply(np.prod)`?

Comment: How would you do this in a vectorized manner? I don't think you can add and subtract from a groupby operation, if you look at the formula in the post you need to do that to cumulate returns properly.